# Change the text direction in WPF FlowDocument TableCell

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, tablecell

I'm trying to create a simple table in a WPF FlowDocument that has rotated text in some of the cells. In Microsoft Word you can easily change the text direction of a table cell but I haven't been able to find a way in a WPF FlowDocument.

Any idea on how to rotate the text 90 degrees or change the text direction. I've tried a few things but the text doesn't wrap and size as desired.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Look into using the **BlockUIContainer** and **RotateTransform**

**Example:**

```
<TableCell>
  <BlockUIContainer>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World">
      <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"></RotateTransform>
      </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
    </TextBlock>
 </BlockUIContainer>
</TableCell>
```

Comment: I've current got this, but I've got issues. For example everything is aligned to the top, rather than bottom. And it doesn't like to word wrap well. :S

Comment: I'll take a look if you want to update your question with the XAML you currently have. I don't have any experience with FlowDocuments, but like trying to figure things out.

Comment: Change the value of "Angle" to change the direction. if the angle is 90 is shows bottom and if it is -90 (or 270) is show above. The Angle works with 360 Degrees.